# Printing two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this two-dimensial array array[y][x] (where x is horizontal and y vertical):

```
3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 4 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 2 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And I need to print it like this:

```
3 1 2 2 1 4 1 2 2
2 4 4 4 3 2 3 3 3
  3       5
          1
```

How would I do this using c++?

Note that there are no empty lines. If the whole column only has zero's in them, there shouldn't be an `endl`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What happens if your row has `0`s in between other numbers, i.e.: `3 2 0 0 1 0 ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over and print out each element. You can flip the elements around by swapping the indices used to get the value out of the array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

int gridWidth = 10;
int gridHeight = 10;
int cellWidth = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++){
    bool anyVals = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++){
        int val = array[i][j]; //Swap i and j to change the orientation of the output
        if(val == 0){
             std::cout << std::setw(cellWidth) << " ";
        }
        else{
             anyVals = true;
             std::cout << std::setw(cellWidth) << val;
        }
    }
    if(anyVals)
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Remember that if you swap `i` and `j` then you will need to swap `gridWidth` and `gridHeight`.

Just to avoid confusion `std::setw(cellWidth)` thing is a convenient way to print fixed-width text (like text that must always be two characters long). It takes whatever you print out and adds spaces to it to make it the right length.

Comment: If I use this I get a lot of empty lines, for all the collumns without a number in them..

Comment: Thank you so much! But I think `bool anyVals = false;` should be above the second for loop (but within the first) so that it doesn't change back to false everytime.. After changing that everything works perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

Take the transpose of your matrix , make 2 loops(outer and inner ) and print only if the no is greater than zero and print space for every zero. when you go back again to the outer loop ,print new line .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        if (array[i][j] != 0)
            cout << array[i][j];
        else
            cout << " ";
    cout << endl;
```